# Terminus as an instant?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent has [Sensei's Divining Top](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sensei%27s%20Divining%20Top) in play on my turn, can he activate it in response to my attack phase in order to play [Terminus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Terminus) for its miracle cost?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your opponent can do this, as long as the Terminus is the first card drawn that turn. It doesn't matter whose turn it is, or that Terminus is a sorcery, Miracle will trigger if it is the first card drawn on by that player on that turn.

From the [Avacyn Restored Mechanics](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/avacyn-restored-mechanics-2012-04-09-0) article:

> As you draw an instant or sorcery with miracle, if it's the first card you've drawn this turn, you can immediately reveal it. When you do so, you may cast it for its miracle cost. It doesn't matter whether it's an instant or sorcery; if you choose to cast it, you do so right away, even if it's at a time (such as your draw step) when you couldn't normally cast it.

And the CR:

> **702.93a** Miracle is a static ability linked to a triggered ability (see rule 603.10). "Miracle [cost]" means "You may reveal this card from your hand as you draw it if it's the first card you've drawn this turn. When you reveal this card this way, you may cast it by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he can.

It's a common misconception that you are forbidden from casting Sorcery spells outside of your turn. There's no such restriction. Priority simply doesn't give you the option to cast a Sorcery when it's not your turn.

But Priority isn't the only rule or effect that allows you to cast spells. Miracle is one too.

> 702.93a Miracle is a static ability linked to a triggered ability (see rule 603.10). “Miracle [cost]” means “You may reveal this card from your hand as you draw it if it’s the first card you’ve drawn this turn. When you reveal this card this way, **you may cast it** by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost.”

Unlike Priority, Miracle doesn't check the type of the card or whose turn it is.

Comment: You also need the stack to be empty and it be either of your main phases to play a sorcery. Your answer could be more specific.

Comment: @Neil Meyer, That's totally wrong. The stack DOESN'T need to be empty, and it DOESN'T need to be one of your main phases. In fact, in the presented scenario, you are allowed to cast it even though the stack isn't empty, and even though it's not one of your main phases. Those are some of the conditions required for Priority to allow you to cast Sorceries, and the whole point of this answer is that this is completely inapplicable here because you aren't relying on Priority but the (optional) instruction to cast it found in the delayed triggered ability created by Miracle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an opponent can use Sensei's Divining Top, or any other instant-speed draw effect, to draw and play a Miracle like Terminus on your turn. The rules for [Miracle](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Miracle) (702.93a) say

> Miracle is a static ability linked to a triggered ability (see rule 603.10). "Miracle [cost]" means "You may reveal this card from your hand as you draw it if it's the first card you've drawn this turn. **When you reveal this card this way, you may cast it by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost.**"

So, when your opponent activates the Top's ability, the following steps happen:

1. They draw Terminus, and put the Top on top of their Libary.
2. Terminus is the first card they draw that turn, so miracle ability allows them to reveal it.
3. Revealing it triggers the Miracle triggered ability.
4. The Miracle triggered ability starts to resolve, and they choose to cast Terminus for {W}. They are casting Terminus as part of the process of resolving the ability, so **normal timing rules do not apply**.
5. Terminus resolves.